# Windows Service Startup for different logons

Tags: c++, service, windows-7

I have 2 windows services,

1. Service1 - logon as domain user   ( automatic )
2. Service2 - logon as Local System  ( automatic delayed start )

Service1 connects to remote systems and Service2 uses Service1 to communicate to remote systems when it's launched.

I want to know which service gets started first and how can I prevent ( or make sure that ) service 2 starts after service 1

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you might want to set up service dependencies.

Comment: That's another issue, Service 2 cannot dependent on Service 1 at startup because, service 2 is supposed to do other things even if Service 1 fails